# How to use HTTP Methods in JAVA with Play Framework

Tags: java, javascript, playframework, xmlhttprequest

I really dont understand much of How Play Framework interact with Java (i use eclipse as IDE)
so please bear with me if my explanation is a bit incomprehensible

what i am trying to do is a 1-page webpage (localhost:9000) that could look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtRFF.png *(i only have 1 rep so i think can't put image; just a link)*

THINGS I NEED TO KNOW:
1) How Does HTTP Methods interact with Playframework
2) How can I Delete, Edit entries

currently What i only know is how to populate students

**code from controllers.Application.Java:**

```
    public static Result addStudents(){

    Student student = Form.form(Student.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    student.save();
    return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }

public static Result getStudents(){

List<Student> students = new Model.Finder(String.class, Student.class).all();
return ok(toJson(students));
}
```

**code from models.Student.java**

```
@Entity
public class Student extends Model{

@Id
public String Id;
public String name;
public String course;
```

}

**code from views.index.scala.html** 
*(I use Java not scala but i really don't know about the difference so i retained the intex.scala.html)*

```
@main("Welcome to Play") {
<form action="@routes.Application.addStudents()" method="post">
<input name="name">
<input course="course">
<input type="submit">
</form>
}
```

**code from conf.evolutions.routes**

```
 POST    /student                   controllers.Application.addStudents()
 GET     /student                   controllers.Application.getStudents()
```

Comment: w,why do i get down voted without a reason? is my question irrelevant or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This completely depends on your needs. You will probably need to learn some ajax, and then learn how to work with requests in the play framework. You can learn ajax basics [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).[Here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaBodyParsers) you can learn to parse the data you can send with ajax.

For example:

Javascript

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = "{"Hi"};
req.open("GET", "http://localhost:9000/service, true);
req.send(data);
```

Java

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result index() {
    RequestBody body = request().body();
    return ok(body.asJson()).as("text/json");
}
```

Also, you will need to import `play.mvc.Http`. I am not sure about the javascript, my ajax is a little rusty.

This will simply echo the response back , but it shows the basics.

Comment: thank you for answering; just a quick question how do i determine the content of request.body()? or does the request.body() contains all strings from a single textbox?